# Creating a Lorenz curve with the R convey package

Tags: r

I've been working with the `convey` package and have run into an issue that I'm not sure how to address.

I'm trying to create a Lorenz curve based on a `svyrepdesign` of 11 years of ACS PUMS data that I created, then ran `convey_prep` on before subsetting down to a single year. When I run the following line:

```
`svylorenz(~INCSIM, test, seq(0, 1, .1), alpha = 0.05, na.rm=TRUE)`
```

I get NAs in each quantile bin and the following warning:

There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)

```
`Warning messages:
1: In sum(weights[weights != 0] * x[weights != 0]) :
  integer overflow - use sum(as.numeric(.))
2: In sum(weights[weights != 0] * x[weights != 0]) :
  integer overflow - use sum(as.numeric(.))`
```

.....repeated 50 times

Not sure what I'm doing wrong but would appreciate any thoughts!

Comment: This is because your numbers are too big. Try reducing your font size in RStudio.

Comment: Interesting idea - I did try that but no luck. I'm also working on a big display so there's plenty of room for whatever is happening on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Ah - I discovered the problem. For some reason, the income variable in my data frame was stored as an integer, though most everything else is numeric. Changing it to numeric solved the problem.